# Can ios local notifications execute business logic?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement. Assuming that there is a database of jokes in the app, a piece of data is retrieved from the jokes every hour and displayed to the user in a notification manner. Can I use local notifications? I checked a lot of information and said it is local The notification cannot execute any business logic, that is, there is no way to get data

Comment: Does your business logic stands for CRUD operations on a local database?

Comment: You can choose the joke to show at the time of schedule of the local notification, no need to run some code at time of invocation.